# qtcreator - undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name16

Tags: qt

I just upgraded to xubuntu 18.10 and qt is not working for me anymore. I already removed and reinstalled it, but it did not help. I get the following error message on the terminal, apparently some sqlite dependency is not right.

```
$ qtcreator
qtcreator: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name16
```

Comment: I solved it, basically identical to the issues in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253059/symbol-lookup-errors-in-qt-dynamically-linked-libraries. I had manually put libsqlite3* files into /usr/local/lib, which caused the error. After removing them, everythin is fine. Issue can be closed.

Comment: it's `lib*q*sqlite.so`, not `libsqlite.so`.