# How to compile the Sqlite plugin for Qt 6.4.1 with the define SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION

Tags: sqlite, qt, plugins

I am trying to upgrade my app to Qt version 6. In order to do this, I nee to compile the MySql and Sqlite plugins. Sqlite needs to have the functionality to load user-defined functions which is done by compiling Sqlite3 with the define SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION

I found the procedure documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html)

My initial approach was to generate the Sqlite plugin to use the system Sqlite library which I have already compiled with SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION. Here is my command to build the generate the build:

```
qt-cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ~/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Qt/6.4.1 -DFEATURE_system_sqlite=ON -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=~/Projects/sqlite-amalgamation-3390300 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Projects/sqlite-amalgamation-3390300
```

Unfortunately, building the plugin failed:

> allen@layout-pc2:~/Qt/6.4.1/Src/build-sqldrivers$ cmake --build .
> [ 10%] Automatic MOC for target QMYSQLDriverPlugin
> [ 10%] Built target QMYSQLDriverPlugin_autogen
> Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target QMYSQLDriverPlugin
> [ 50%] Built target QMYSQLDriverPlugin
> [ 60%] Automatic MOC for target QSQLiteDriverPlugin
> [ 60%] Built target QSQLiteDriverPlugin_autogen
> Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target QSQLiteDriverPlugin
> [ 70%] Building CXX object sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/QSQLiteDriverPlugin_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
> [ 80%] Building CXX object sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/qsql_sqlite.cpp.o
> [ 90%] Building CXX object sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/smain.cpp.o
> [100%] Linking CXX shared module ../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/qsql_sqlite.cpp.o: in function `QSQLiteResultPrivate::initColumns(bool)': /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp:178: <br>undefined reference to` sqlite3_column_table_name16'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> gmake[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969202/qtcreator-undefined-symbol-sqlite3-column-table-name16): *** [sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/build.make:130: plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so] Error 1
> gmake[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html): *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:226: sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
> gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2

I found a post about this error [undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_table_name16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969202/qtcreator-undefined-symbol-sqlite3-column-table-name16)

I removed all occurrences of libsqlite3.so except the one I compiled but could not resolve the error. I then decided to go with the built in Sqlite plugin and changed my command to "-DFEATURE_system_sqlite=OFF" aftter removing CMakeCache.txt. This time I was able to build and install the plugins but my app failed when it could not install my user defined function.

I then investigated how how to get the required define included in the build and found defines for the build in sqlite's ~/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/CMakeLists.txt I added the define SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION in the list of defines and changed it in another place where it was SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION.
I cleared out my build_sqldrivers folder and ran my configure command but even though the build was successful the plugin still fails because load extension is not configured.

So, what am I doing wrong?

---

In reviewing the output I came across an error to the effect that I was using "Unix MakeFiles" instead of "Ninja" which I should do at my own risk. So, I decided to start with a new copy of 8.4.1
I used this command:

> ```
> ./configure -sql-mysql -sql-sqlite -system-sqlite
> ```

I received an error:

```
  Configuring submodule 'qtbase'
  CMake Error: Error: generator : Ninja
  Does not match the generator used previously: Unix Makefiles
  Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory    or choose a different binary directory.
```

Deleting the the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory did not resolve the problem so I pulled a fresh copy of 6.4.1 and installed ninja:
[Install Ninja Build System on Ubuntu 22.04](https://lindevs.com/install-ninja-build-system-on-ubuntu)

I pulled a fresh copy of 6.4.1 an ran configure again. After a while, the configure ended with:

```
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/Src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/Src/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:965   (message):
    CMake exited with code 1.
```

However, qtbase seemed to have been configured so I'll try the sql drivers.

the command:

```
qt-cmake -G Ninja ~/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Qt/6.4.1
```

returned

```
  Qt Sql Drivers:
    DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
    InterBase .............................. no
    MySql .................................. yes
    OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
    ODBC ................................... no
    PostgreSQL ............................. no
    SQLite ................................. yes
      Using system provided SQLite ......... no
```

Adding the -DFeature_system_sqlite does not work:

```
allen@layout-pc2:~/Qt/6.4.1/Src/build_sqldrivers$ qt-cmake -G Ninja ~/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Qt/6.4.1 -DFEATURE_system_sqlite=YES
```

'system_sqlite' is changed from OFF to YES
CMake Warning at /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake  /Qt6/QtSetup.cmake:325 (message):

```
  Re-configuring in existing build folder.  Some features will be
  re-evaluated automatically.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6BuildInternals/Qt6BuildInternalsConfig.cmake:237 (include)
  /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6BuildInternals/Qt6BuildInternalsConfig.cmake:333 (qt_build_internals_set_up_private_api)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (qt_prepare_standalone_project)


CMake Warning at /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtFeature.cmake:246 (message):
  Reset FEATURE_system_sqlite value to OFF, because it doesn't meet its
  condition after reconfiguration.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtFeature.cmake:396 (qt_feature_check_and_save_user_provided_value)
  /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtFeature.cmake:606 (qt_evaluate_feature)
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (qt_feature_module_end)
-- Configuration summary shown below. It has also been written to /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/Src/build_sqldrivers/config.summary
-- Configure with --log-level=STATUS or higher to increase       CMake's message verbosity. The log level does not persist across reconfigurations.

-- Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. yes
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/allen/Qt/6.4.1    /Src/build_sqldrivers
```

In reviewing entries in CMakeCache.txt in found several references to SQLite. After insuring that the location of my libsqlite3.so and the l
include directory were correct, the configure completed successfully but when the build was done, it failed with:

> allen@layout-pc2:~/Qt/6.4.1/Src$ cmake --build .
> [715/10017] Linking CXX shared module qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so
> FAILED: qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so
> : && /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--version-script,/home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.version -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -shared  -o qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/QSQLiteDriverPlugin_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/qsql_sqlite.cpp.o qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/smain.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:/home/allen/Qt/6.4.1/Src/qtbase/lib:  /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so  qtbase/lib/libQt6Sql.so.6.4.1  qtbase/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.4.1 && :
> /usr/bin/ld: qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/CMakeFiles/QSQLiteDriverPlugin.dir/qsql_sqlite.cpp.o: in function `QSQLiteResultPrivate::initColumns(bool)': qsql_sqlite.cpp:(.text+0x2496): undefined reference to` sqlite3_column_table_name16'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> [720/10017] Building CXX object qtbase.../CMakeFiles/Test.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.gch
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Comment: Extension loading must be enabled at run-time on a per-connection basis. Does the Qt wrapper/plugin not have a way of doing that?

Comment: The ability to load extensions at runtime by the Sqlite driver is disabled by default in the driver provided by Qt because it potentially provides a way for malicious code to be executed on a user's pc. As a result, if you want to be able to load user defined functions as you can in MySql or Sql Server, Sqlite must be recompiled.

Comment: The link error, undefined reference t 'sqlite3_column_table_name16' is a symbol insqlite3ext.which is supposed to be used when building sqlite when load extension is enabled. However this file does not appear in the Qt qtbase/src/3rdParty/sqlite directory. So the problem seems to related to the absence of sqlite3ext.h.

Comment: `sqlite3ext.h` is the header file used when compiling a loadable extension library, not the SQLite engine itself. The `SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION` symbol is not a recognized or supported compile-time [option](https://sqlite.org/compile.html) for SQLite. To load an extension at run-time, you must call the `sqlite3_load_extension()` API or use the `load_extension()` SQL function. In order to do that, you first have to call the `sqlite3_enable_load_extension()` API or use the `sqlite3_db_config()` API with the `SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION` option. How does Qt do that?

Comment: If SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION is provided when compiling sqlite3.c certain API functions which provide the functionality to load and link to an external library or dll. sqlite3ext.h when compiled with sqlite3.c exposes and exports internal sqlite routines so that the external library being loaded can access sqlite3's functions. The libqsqlite3.so lib which is the sqlite3 plugin needs to link with sqlite3 internal functions, one of which is the 'sqlite3_column_table_name16' What seems to be missing is this define: #define sqlite3_column_table_name16    sqlite3_api->column_table_name16

Comment: Continuing to try things: Took out the defines for amalgamation  files and the build was successful. However now my app fails with:error loading functions = /home/allen/Projects/Mapper/build-mapper-Desktop_Qt_6_4_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/mapper_app/mapper: undefined symbol: sqlite3_extension_init Unable to fetch row

Answer (score 0):

The unresolved error on sqlite3_column_table_name16 was the result of not compiling the sqlite library with the DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA define. Recompiling Sqlite with that define resulted in successfully compiling the Sqlite plugin. So, I believe the problem is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar problem when I try to build databases/qt5-sqldrivers-sqlite3 port in FreeBSD system.

After enabling MATADATA option in databases/sqlite3, everything works fine.